# Ruby Permission Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

When trying to do `gem install bundle` I get this:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should **really** consider researching [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) for managing your rubies and gems.

Answer (score 2):

root access with sudo

```
sudo gem install bundle
```

Comment: Thanks. When I did that, I got this:

ERROR:  While generating documentation for bundle-0.0.1
... MESSAGE:   exit
... RDOC args: --ri --op /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/doc/bundle-0.0.1/ri lib --title bundle-0.0.1 Documentation --quiet

Comment: Using `sudo` to install a gem on Mac OS isn't recommended. Apple installs Ruby for their own use, not ours. It's better to use RVM or rbenv to install a Ruby in a sandbox, and leave Apple's Ruby alone.